# Can you place a button within a table that has row click events?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

So im trying to create a web interface for a database that im working with. And basically the tbale has rows of data and i have set it up so that when a row is clicked a side panel comes in and displays some info. Now i have also added button in the first column of the table so that the information in that row will be saved some where but I cant get a click event working on that button.

Is it possible that the row click event is over powering the add button click event in the main centre panel.

row click function

```
function addRowClicks() {
        var table = document.getElementById("resultsTable");
        var rows = table.rows; // or table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            rows[i].onclick = (function() {
                var cnt = i; 
                return function() {
                    var specimenID = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                    $.post('../scripts/displaySpecimenSideBar.php',{specimenID:specimenID},function(data){
                        var returnedInformation = data; 
                        $(".sidebarRight-innner").html(data);
                        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                            active:false,
                            heightStyle: "content",
                            collapsible: true});

                        var $marginLefty = $(".sidebarRight");
                        $marginLefty.animate({
                          marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('margin-left'),10) == 0 ?
                            $marginLefty.outerWidth() :
                            0
                        });

                        var sidebarRightOffset = jQuery(window).width()- $(".navElement").outerWidth()-5;
                        $(".sidebarRight").animate($(".sidebarRight").css("left",sidebarRightOffset));

                        mainContentWidth = jQuery(window).width() - jQuery(".sidebarleft").outerWidth() - jQuery(".navElement").outerWidth()-5;
                        $(".main-content").animate($(".main-content").css("width",mainContentWidth));
                        //jQuery('.main-content').width(mainContentWidth);
                        //alert(data);
                    });
                }    
            })(i);
        }
    }
```

buttons are generated in a php

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($results)){
            $resultsString = $resultsString."<tr>";
                for ($z = 0; $z < $numOfFields; $z++){
                    if ($z==0){$resultsString = $resultsString.'<td><input type="button" id="test" name="Specimen'.$numberOfResults.'" value="ADD"></td>';
                               $resultsString = $resultsString."<td id='ID".$numberOfResults."'>".$row[$fieldsArray[$z]]."</td>";
                              }
                    else{
                        $resultsString = $resultsString."<td>".$row[$fieldsArray[$z]]."</td>";
                    }
                }
            $resultsString = $resultsString."</tr>";
            $numberOfResults++;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to have the button working inside such a row.

Comment: How would i make that work?

Comment: If button is dynamically added to the DOM, you should delegate event. Now if you want specific help, you have to provide relevant code of what you are talking about...

Comment: That depends on your actual setup and problem. If you provide more information, including relevant code, we might be able to help you better.

Comment: Hard to say for sure without an actual code sample but sounds like it may be a good use for event.preventDefault(). http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: And where are you trying to bind the event handler to the button? And what is the actual problem? "It doesn't work" is not a proper problem description. Since you are using jQuery, you should learn how to do event handling with jQuery: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/ . I'd argue that you better post the generated markup, not the php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are having trouble with your button events, although your question is missing a lot of info.

Maybe something like this?

```
$(".row-btn").click(function() {
     // show row info
});

$(".column-save-btn").click(function() {
     // submit form/ajax request to save
});
```

Perhaps if you add more info we can better understand what's all going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind the event on every column of the table but the one that has the button.